# OOP Three.JS not working, some elements aren't called in console

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js

I am having difficulty with making my Three.js OOP. The original script works and shows three y-rotational planes. When I check in my console it seems to appear that some objects aren't called even though I created them. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I have been trying to figure out the issue with the console log of my live server and I think the problem is in the classes card or mesh, but when I adjust something it gives me more errors.

For so far I have made this:

```
var renderer, scene, camera;
      var speed = 0.03; // speed for rotation

      class Plane {
          constructor(geometryFront) {
            this.geometryFront = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(90, 110, 1, 1);
          }
          applyMatrix() {
            this.geometryFront.applyMatrix(
              new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI)
            );
          }
        }

        class Material {
          constructor(material, imgMaterial) {
            //console.log("hi, i am working");
            this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
              map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgMaterial),
            });
          }
        }

        class Card {
          constructor(addCard, xCard, yCard, zCard) {
            this.addCard = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add(this.addCard);
            this.addCard.position.set(xCard, yCard, zCard);
            this.addCard.rotation.y += speed;
          }
          cardMesh(addMesh) {
            this.addCard.add(addMesh);
          }
        }

        class Mesh {
          constructor(addMesh, geometry, material, linkCard) {
            this.addMesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
            linkCard.cardMesh(this.addMesh);
          }
        }

      preSet();
      cardAssets();
      animate(); 

      function preSet() {
        // renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // bg moet onder scene
        const loaderBG = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        const bgTexture = loaderBG.load("temp-bg.jpeg");
        scene.background = bgTexture;

        // camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
          40,
          window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
          1,
          10000
        );
        camera.position.z = 300;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      }

      function cardAssets() {
        
        var geometryA = new Plane(geometryA);
        var geometryB = new Plane(geometryB);
        geometryB.applyMatrix();

        var materialA = new Material(materialA, "a-crime-to-design.jpg");
        var materialB = new Material(materialB, "bg-crime.jpg");

        var cardA = new Card(cardA, -120, 0, 0);
        var cardB = new Card(cardB, -120, 0, 0);

        var meshA = new Mesh(meshA, geometryA, materialA, cardA);
        var meshB = new Mesh(meshB, geometryB, materialB, cardB); 


      } // end cardAssets

      function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate); //asking animation frames
          renderer.render(scene, camera); //rendering
        }
```

The console doesn't give any errors, except for a missing favicon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistake when calling `new THREE.Mesh(...)`. First, in your `Mesh` class, `this.geometry` and `this.material` is nowhere defined. In this code, you are calling `new THREE.Mesh` with both `undefined`.

```js
var meshA = new Mesh(meshA, geometryA, materialA, cardA);
```

```js
class Mesh {
  constructor(addMesh, geometry, material, linkCard) {
    this.addMesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    linkCard.cardMesh(this.addMesh);
  }
}
```

Second, with `geometryA` and `materialA`, you are passing instances of your custom `Plane` and `Material` classes to the constructor. Calling the `THREE.Mesh` constructor with these instances will fail, because `THREE.Mesh` accepts only `TRHEE.BufferGeometry` and `THREE.Material`. You would need to pass the according properties, in this case `geometryFront` and `material`:

```
new THREE.Mesh(geometry.geometryFront, material.material);
```

In general, I find your code very weird. I don't understand why you pass the variable into the constructor? The variable at this point is still undefined and it is nowhere used within the constructor method.

```
var meshA = new Mesh(meshA, ...
```

Comment: Hi, I understand what you said. I do have one question. The code works right now, card is visible and I understand you find the code odd, i will talk this over with my teacher tomorrow on how to make it "less weird". The rotation function still isn't working and I was wondering if you could give me a tip on how to fix it. The information that you provided above was very usefull to me and is now included in the code with some comments.

Comment: `.applyMatrix()` doesn't exist on `BufferGeometry`. You need to use `.applyMatrix4()` (you forgot the `4`). An alternative is to use `.rotateY(Math.PI)`.